# Flask: Include common template to multiple blueprints

Tags: flask, include, jinja2

How could I implement a common template to be included in two Flask blueprints?
I am trying to create the following structure in my application:

```
 app
  +-- bp
  |    +-- hello
  |    |   +-- templates
  |    |   |    +-- hello
  |    |   |        +-- hello.html
  |    |   +-- routes.py
  |    +-- world
  |        + etc
  +-- templates
       +-- common_incl.html
```

in hello.html, I try to include another file by `{% include '/templates/common_incl.html' %}` but I always get a TemplateNotFound exception.

I would not like to expose the common_incl.html in static folder, as it isn't static but has Jinja variables expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/#templates might provide some guidance.

Depending on the nature of your application (and your blueprints) either put the base templates in the application's `templates` folder, or use a third blueprint that does nothing but hold common templates for your two templates.

Comment: I did not succeed to refer any template outside the current blueprint. Propably I consider duplicting the comon code snippet in all blueprint templates needed.

Comment: The Flask Mega Tutorial has a working example you can study. https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.23/app